# Delete button in TableViewCell change frame

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can change the position of delete button when tableviewcell in the edit style, use following code

```
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
[super didTransitionToState:state];

if(state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
{

    for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) 
    {
        if([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
        {    
            NSLog(@"find");
            CGRect f = v.frame;
            deleteView = v;
            NSLog(@"delete view %@",[deleteView description]);
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

            v.frame = CGRectMake(200, 10, f.size.width, f.size.height);
            UIControl *vs = [[v subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
            CGRect fs = vs.frame;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
            fs.origin.x -=20;
            vs.frame = fs;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

        }
    }

}

}
```

use this way I can change the position of delete button. But each time the delete button appears, it moves in from the right side of my tableviewcell with `animation`, and finally it located at the position I specified..... I just want to set the button frame before it appears, but now i have no idea. my english is poor ...thanks everybody ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are  two  messages: `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:`.

I think you can use the `delegate` to update the appearance of the table view appropriately.

Comment: thanks for your advice...but i've use all these delegate in my tableview and I can use the delete function. and now i just want to change the frame or position of the delete button before it appears, or stop the animation when delete button appears.  thank you.....